# Placing PNG in shape

Tags: java, android, checkbox, styles, png

I want to customize a CheckBox and I have a custom checkmark image for that CheckBox as a PNG file.

Is it possible to use that PNG?
If so, then how can I do it?

I would like to change the CheckBox's background.

Comment: Are you looking for [`layer-list`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) (or [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) at runtime)? It does exactly what the name says: draw layers in a top-to-bottom fashion. A layer can be composed of a colour, another drawable (i.e. a shape), bitmap references, or even another (nested) layer drawable.

Comment: Please read [Meta: Should I answer "Is it possible?" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions).